# self refrence inside swift closure return nil some time

Tags: swift, weak-references, completionhandler

I am accessing instance method inside closure in swift, **self** reference become **nil** in some cases which result crash my program. I tried to access using `[weak self]` but it failed to call the instance method when **self** is `nil`.

```
[weak self] () -> () in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix this issue by making strong instance while creating it, in my case this weak variable was making nil to self. Thanks all for providing suggestion for my queries.

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of `[weak self]` is to not create a reference to self (probably to avoid circular links and memory leaks) so that it can be released.  If that happens, then `self` will be `nil`.

You should either not use `[weak self]` or, better yet probably, be prepared to handle the case of `self` having been released and set to `nil`.

```
guard let strong = self else { return }
```

Take the example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class Foo {
    let name : String

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) { [weak self] in
            print(self!.name)
        }
    }
}

Foo(name:"freddie")

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

In this case, you'll get a crash, because self is released before the async callback is made.

You can either change the `asyncAfter` call to be:

```
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            print(self.name)
        }
```

will guarantee that self isn't released until after the callback is made.

Or you can use something like:

```
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) { [weak self] in
            guard let strong = self else { print("self released") ; return }
            print(strong.name)
        }
```

Comment: In my case I am drafting code as below which result crash. `let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {[weak self] data, response, error in guard let weakSelf = self else { return } weakSelf.downloadFinished(data, response: response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, error: error) } `

Comment: Note that `weakSelf` is in fact "strong" as it can never be `nil`, counter to the meaning of `weak`. Also, how are you verifying that that is the code causing the crash?

Comment: @BallpointBen : I added a debug log to track it. It was crashing before when I was accessing **self** directly but now it fails to call next line when **self** reference is nil

Answer (score 1):

The riddle is in where you've placed the root object of the instance. I too had such scenario where I'd created my object inside a function and used it in a closure under the same function.

It's look like:

```
class A {
    var myProp = ""
    func nilSelf() {
        closureFunc { [weak self] in
            self?.myProp
        }
    }

    func closureFunc(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        //There is some work need to be completed to call the closure
        closure()
    }
}

class B {
    func main() {
        let obj = A()
        //I called the below func too inside another closure
        obj.nilSelf()
    }
}
```

I called the `main()` of `class B` somewhere, at the time the closure is being called the `main` method has completed its work, so the variable `obj` is nullified. Hence the problem occurs.

To solve this move the line 'let obj = A()' to the class scope.

I hope this might help you or others who is seeking solution for this problem.
If I missed anything kindly correct me.