# Protocol delegate not working sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, weak-references

I am having an issue with a protocol delegate not always responding.  Here is my implementation:

```
protocol CameraViewDelegate: class {
    func didTapCancel(sender: CameraView)
    func didFinishSelectingPhoto(image: UIImage, sender: CameraView)
}
```

In the CameraView class I have:

```
weak var delegate: CameraViewDelegate?
```

and

```
@IBAction func cancelButtonTapped() {
    delegate?.didTapCancel(self)
}

@IBAction func sendPhotoTapped() {
    if let image = selectedImage {
        delegate?.didFinishSelectingPhoto(image, sender: self)
    }
}
```

In the other class, I have:

```
class PhotoController: CameraViewDelegate {
```

and

```
func didTapCancel(sender: CameraView) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    RootViewController.shared().navigateToHome()
}

func didFinishSelectingPhoto(image: UIImage, sender: CameraView) {
    let photo = MyPhoto(image: image)
    sendPhoto(photo)
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

This works 95% of the time, but I am getting a weird bug where the delegate fails to respond sometimes.  If I hit the button cancel or sendPhoto, the button appears to press but nothing happens.  I know this is the delegate failing to respond because the other buttons in CameraView that don't use the delegate still work normally.

Any ideas?

Comment: how have you set the `delegate` property of your `CameraView` class in the _other class_?

Comment: Does it happen when you do things super quick? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43147376/5175709). Paulo's answer is likely a dangerous one, it would create memory leaks.

Comment: @Honey It was just a quick and dirty debugging tip, haha! Anyway, improved answer to keep OP on the right track. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Honey it seems to happen on first launch of a fresh install consistently.  If I quit the app and open again, it works as expected.

Comment: I'm just spitballing: very likely something is `nil` somewhere and while you're running/messaging a function onto it. Likely you're not finding out where because you're *safe unwrapping*. Like somewhere as the above linked answer you're releasing `self` to early or releasing an object to early. It might help that you try **forced unwrapping** so you will *crash* at the `nil` object and pinpoint it. Once you found it then edit your question with the possible nil object

Answer (score 3):

**Debugging Tip**. Try to temporarily remove the `weak` qualifier from your `delegate` property.  You might be releasing your delegate object too soon (i.e., zero [strong references](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) to it).

If this fixes your issue, then you found your bug, congrats! Please insert again the `weak` qualifier so you don't leak memory unnecessarily — and remember to keep a strong reference to it elsewhere :-)

Comment: You should be giving an example with _how to keep a strong reference to it elsewhere_.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to assign other view controller delegate = self where you from push the camera

Answer (score 0):

Check if you set `delegate` when you initialize your camera view. Try something like:

```
let cameraView = CameraView() 
cameraView.delegate = self
```